# how can i best bend/curve a mesh or fix this glitchy looking bend?

Tags: modeling, mesh

i have an imported model of a tank/mech with a tank barrel on it, im planning to use this model for posing purposes, in the program it exports from i can rotate the turret and pose it in many ways however in blender i need to bent the turret backward on itself like seen in superhero movies or in movies where a gun barrel is bent. [image: tank cannon bent]

i have tried using, bevel tool (doesnt work), the deform tool (doesnt work), and the curve modifier (partly works but glitches) wherever the vertex group mesh section connects to a non curved part of the mesh there is a straight then sudden 90 degree glitchy looking turn [image: curve working yet glitching other mesh area] i dont know how to fix this issue as any selecting just moves the next part of the mesh as the glitched turn.

Comment: Simply add some loop cuts into the "too straight" part. Ctrl+R, then move your mouse near this part, and to add several parts, use mouse wheel or page up/page down... for the other aspects, all depends on Hulk...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems using the warp tool works the best if you can fiddle with it to make sure it perfect, because you will get shortened or enlongated meshes for no real reason but it seems to work better than curves

Comment: Curve modifier is rather useful and workable; it's just the matter of handling with origin points. See [How to curve mesh](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34598/how-to-curve-my-mesh) and [How to bend large model](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10730/how-to-bend-a-large-model).

Answer (score 0):

Using a curve modifier and starting from this position (curve modifier on the canon) :

[image]

- Go to edit mode
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, the move to the straight cylinder part and mouse wheel or use <kbd>page up</kbd> to increase the number of cuts
- Validate using <kbd>LMB</kbd>, eventually move the cuts, then <kbd>LMB</kbd> again (or escape to stay at the initial position)

[image]

Comment: i actually have attempted to add more loop cuts to it, it doesnt help as it just moves the flattened spot further back, i had the problem before and tried making it work with vertex groups to which it mostly did but that flat part is from an unselected section that isnt part of the bend intentionally, on the inmae of the tank i put on it shows the flat part originating from the end of a thicker piece of the barrel which is my stopping point. more loop cuts just effects the already bent part not the flat part as thats apparently just the connecting faces between the stopping point.

Comment: i have managed to curve the barrel by moving the selection along the edge loops and rotating them that way, not the best method but apparently the only working method. i still dont get how to make the curve modifier work porperly as they all warp and distort meshes far too much