# Why are my objects flattened or distorted when using the Shrinkwrap modifier?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

Perhaps I'm using the wrong modifier, but I'm trying to conform a series of nuts to a curved plane. I first thought the shrinkwrap modifier would be the best way to go , but I'm confused by the results I get.

My results show the nuts either being flattened (project) or being distorted violently (other settings)

What am I not realizing here?

Many thanks

Sam

[image: problem]

[image: intention]

[image: wireframe]

Comment: Your are using the wrong modifier, this is the expected behavior, *Shrinkwrap* modifier *is* designed to flatten things. Use a *Curve* modifier instead, or perhaps *Duplifaces*

Comment: you can try using a latice: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33434/how-to-add-curve-modifier-to-text/60958#60958 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10730/how-to-bend-a-large-model/10731#10731 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26023/in-blender-3d-is-there-any-function-like-flow-along-surface-in-rhino-3d/26048#26048

Answer (score 7):

The [Shrinkwrap Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html) moves vertices against the target object. The effect you are seeing is the intended effect, as it has no notion of maintaining the volume of an object.

To move the whole object, while maintaining the shape of the object, you can use a [Shrinkwrap Constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/relationship/shrinkwrap.html), which will move the object as a whole to place its origin onto the target surface.

[image: sample shrinkwrap constraint]

Comment: how can i apply the constraint

Comment: You [apply the visual tranform](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html#visual-transform).

Comment: Thanks! This explains why none of the instructions I tried to follow worked! :D