# Why is shape with shrinkwrap modifier flat?

Tags: modifiers

I have a sphere and stretched. I have made a curve and i want that curve to be shrinkwrap on it. I add the shrinkwrap modifier on to it but it lost the original shape. Its flat on the surface.
[image]

[image]

How can i get the original shape without going flat on the surface. Any suggestion or help

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/76534/935)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The Shrinkwrap Modifier allows an object to "shrink" to the surface of another object. **It moves each vertex of the object** being modified to the closest position on the surface of the given mesh (using one of the three methods available).

from https://docs.blender.org/manual/ko/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html

So it's totally normal that it's looking like this.

You can use  Vertex Groups:

> The vertex group to control whether and how much each vertex is displaced to its target position. If a vertex is not a member of this group, it is not displaced (same as weight 0).

But in this case it will not help in any easy way. Maybe some detailed Weight Painting could do the trick though.

**This is what you can do instead:**

[image: final]

1. Make **Curve** and convert it to a **Mesh** or just make this shape by **Extruding** single vertex. In this case second option would be faster.
2. Add to it **Shrinkwrap** modifier.
3. Add **Skin** modifier. Turn off **Symmetry X Axis** and check **Smooth Shading**.
4. Add **Subdivision Surface** modifier.
5. Go to **Edit Mode** and select first and last vertex.
6. With **Proportional Editing** turned on and fallof set to **Sphere** hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and scale both vertices as you want.

This is whole setup:

[image: setup]

Comment: The result is perfect.