# Deforming objects along the surface of other objects

Tags: modeling

Hello I have made a chain model and I want to put some objects on it but objects must deform and cover up chain. it should be like this example
[image]

Thank you for your helps.

Comment: in your picture most of the objects don't look deform, but if you have to deform your objects you could use some modifiers like Curve

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried curve, shrink wrap and some other deforming solutions but I couldn't be successful.

Comment: if you're talking about materials like water, grass, road, etc... you should unwrap your meshes and use Image Textures. Then you add all the 3D items like trees, trucks, boats, etc...

Comment: No I am not talking about textures, I am talking about objects, in example objects deform around chain.

Comment: not really, what object are you talking about? It looks like the artist has just rotated a bit the 3D objects so that they stick to the surface, I don't see deformations

Comment: Have you seen containers at the port? They are deformed, not all off them but yes deformed.

Comment: By the way I found a solution. it is miratools and it works perfect. Thank you.

Comment: If you found a good solution for this, you could add an answer yourself, to explain others how you solved it, maybe with a simple example. It would be great. Later you could even accept your own answer...

Comment: Miratools aside - this is how I would approach this using shrinkwrap and lattice - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95975/why-im-not-getting-thickness-with-shrinkwrap-modifier

Answer (score 1):

So one of the cool things about a torus-- which is what a chain link is-- is that it unwraps really nicely.  You seam it twice and it makes a perfect square.  And any tiling texture on that square will tile on the torus.

So what I might try here is to take that knowledge and create some displacement maps for my toruses.  You could build each link's stuff as a flat scene, then render to a height map, and apply that height map as displacement to your torus.  (UV mapping the individual elements would be a different matter though.)

Another option here is to use the Textools addon, which can create flattened versions of meshes.  It rips along UV seams and then creates a flattened shapekey.  From the flattened shapekey, you can surface deform other meshes, then unflatten.

Comment: Thank you. I found an addon called miratools and it worked perfect.