# How can I wrap a cylinder to a curved face?

Tags: modeling, shrinkwrap, surface-deform

I'm modelling a Warhammer Space Marine pauldron (shoulder armour), and for the life of me I can't figure out how to wrap a circle/cylinder to it's curved surface in a way that doesn't drastically warp the circular shape.

[image]

In the above, you can see the pauldron (which has a steep Y/Z axis curve, and shallow X/Y axis curve), and the shape I'm wanting to wrap.

[image] [image]

In the next two images, you can see the shape after my attempt to wrap it. This was achieved by using a plane shrinkwrapped to the pauldron, and transfering it's effect to the cylinder via a surface deform modifier. However, as you can see, the circle is now very warped in the X axis (2nd image) - and isn't really circular at all.

Thus far, my only successful means of improving the shape is to use a lattice to adjust it into a more circular shape, but (as per the below image) you can see this leaves the X axis edges thicker.

[image]

Is there a better way to achieve a uniform wrap that I'm missing?

For context, the effect I'm trying to achieve is similar to below, where the circle is uniform in width, height and depth across the pauldron (Also, as I know Games Workshop use digital modelling to produce their plastic parts, it shows it can be done... somehow):

[image]

Comment: Seems [this](https://blendermarket.com/products/conform-object) might help but you do have to pay for it though. If you don't want to pay, the only thing I can suggest is manually moving the vertices using the snap tool and using either the *Face Project* or *Face Nearest* setting.

Comment: Thanks Orleez - sadly, I've got that add on, but it's not playing nicely with my blender at the moment, so I was looking for a vanilla solution using Blender's core features. Appreciated nonetheless :)

Comment: A Lattice usually works in this kind of situation - one vertex high square grid (with more points for higher accuracy). Deform the “decoration” mesh based on the lattice and then simply Shrinkwrap the lattice onto the target mesh.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why im not getting thickness with shrinkwrap modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95975/why-im-not-getting-thickness-with-shrinkwrap-modifier)