# Is it possible to project an object onto another object's surface?

Tags: modifiers, objects, transforms

What I wanna do is not like a shrinkwrap modifier, but move the the entire object like this:
[image: "cube floating over curved mesh"]

[image: "cube floating over curved mesh"]

Comment: maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26023/in-blender-3d-is-there-any-function-like-flow-along-surface-in-rhino-3d

Comment: and https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/76577/1853

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [shrinkwrap constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/relationship/shrinkwrap.html).

Select the target object.

The original object's origin will move to the surface of the target object.

[image]